# Angular SUM to fields value

Tags: angular, angular-material

Kindly check my code where I am wrong. add(+) function is not working for me. instead of adding, it concatenates. ex: 2 + 2 = 22 it should be 2 + 2 = 4

```
CalculateQty(i){
          let total = this.assetRevaluationForm.get('ItemRec') as FormArray;
          let formGroup = total.controls[i] as FormGroup;
          formGroup
            .get('NewDep')
            .patchValue(formGroup.get ('netBookValue').value + formGroup.get('revaluedAmount').value);   
            
          }
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because the values are read as strings. So "+" doesn't perform an addition, but a string concatenation instead.

Add `type="number"` to your `input` tags.

Alternatively, you could parse the values as numbers, like this `Number(...)`, but this requires extra checks to avoid parsing errors.
For example, if your user types a character in your field, this will result in a `NaN` value.

Answer (score 1):

the value stored in the `formControl` is a string, so it adds it like a string.
wrap it with `Number` :

```
Number(formGroup.get ('netBookValue').value) + Number(formGroup.get('revaluedAmount').value)
```

if you'r using angular 14 you can add type to your `formControl` like this:

```
new FormControl<number>(0)
```

so in this case you can use mathematics operators on the value with no casting...

good luck :)

Comment: Hi Eli may I ask a question again, how to get difference between two dates angular in months

Comment: try it: `endDate.getMonth() -
    startDate.getMonth() +
    12 * (endDate.getFullYear() - startDate.getFullYear())`

Comment: Hi Eli, this my html code <input style="width:300px" class="form-control" type="date" formControlName="newDepSample" > I need to Subtract my formControlName - to DateToday and the answer is in Months is that possble?

Comment: open a new question for it please